# Row was updated or deleted by another transaction-multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I want to restirict user table updation when two threads are working together, which throws "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.dmainc.commons.security.User#4]"
. When second threads hits first starts rolling back and throw the exception.
Actually each thread is modifying the passwordAttemptDate.I need to update this field each time when user is logging, how to perform this operation simulaneously for both thread. I am calling this method within a transaction.

ANY SUGGESSION WILL BE APPRECIATED.

```
 public AuthenticationStatus authenticateEncrypted(User user, String password, ISecurityParameters params,
     Boolean encryptedPassword)
  {
  AuthenticationStatus status = new AuthenticationStatus();
  status.setUser(user);
  status.setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.Status.UNKNOWN_ERROR);

     // hash password
     String hashedPass = (encryptedPassword == true ? password : hashPassword(password, user.getSalt()));

     // compare to stored password and check on attempts if failed
     if(hashedPass.equals(user.getPassword()))
     {
        user.setPasswordAttempts(0);
        //THIS IS GETTING UPDATED EACH TIME
        user.setPasswordAttemptDate(Calendar.getInstance());

        if(getPasswordNotify(user, params) >= 0)
        {
           status.setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.Status.SUCCESS_NOTIFY);
        }
        else if(isPasswordExpired(user, params))
        {
           status.setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.Status.PASSWORD_EXPIRED);
        }
        else
        {
           status.setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.Status.SUCCESS);
        }

        status.setArg(arg);
        return status;
     }
     else
     {
        user.setPasswordAttempts((user.getPasswordAttempts() == null) ? 1 : user.getPasswordAttempts() + 1);
        user.setPasswordAttemptDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        status.setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.Status.FAIL);
     }
  }
  catch(Exception pe)
  {
     if(LOG.isErrorEnabled())
        LOG.error(pe, pe);
  }

  return status;
```

}

User.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.dmainc.commons.security.User" table="userdata">
    <id name="userId" type="long">
        <column name="UserId" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version name="version" type="int">
        <column name="Version" not-null="true" />
    </version>
    <property name="username" type="string">
        <column name="Username" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="FirstName" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="LastName" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="string">
        <column name="Email" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="status" type="string">
        <column name="Status" length="2" />
    </property>

    <property name="passwordAttempts" type="int">
        <column name="PasswordAttempts" />
    </property>
    <property name="passwordAttemptDate" type="calendar">
        <column name="PasswordAttemptDate" length="19" />

    <many-to-one name="organization" class="com.dmainc.commons.security.Organization" fetch="select">
        <column name="OrganizationId" />
    </many-to-one>
    <set name="userpasswords" table="userpasswords" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
        <key>
            <column name="UserId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.dmainc.commons.security.UserPassword" />
    </set>
    <bag name="userroles" table="userrole" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select"  cascade="all,delete-orphan">
        <key>
            <column name="UserId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.dmainc.commons.security.UserRole" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Comment: You should use Session.lock(Object entitty, LockMode lock). Typically, you'll either want to use LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE or LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT. The latter option works only  for DB systems supporting the select ..... for update no wait  syntax (e.g. Oracle, Sql server). Note that you may have to increase trasacaction timeout when changing lock modes)

Comment: when I removed version from hbm its working fine, can this be a possible fix?what will be impact of removing it?, @dsp_user

Comment: Possibly because Hibernate uses <version> for optimistic locking (https://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try enclosing your code in transaction blocks?

something like:

```
Session session = null;  
Transaction tx = null;  

try {  
session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
tx = session.beginTransaction();  
//YOUR CODE HERE 

tx.commit();  

}catch (Exception ex) {  
ex.printStackTrace();  
tx.rollback();  
}  
finally {session.close();}
```